# Understanding Basic of Assembly

Tags: assembly

Can anyone give a briefly explain of what is "base address", " Offset", "pointer" in assembly language?
How they related to each other?

I am learning how to work with olldbg. I am new to assembly language.

Comment: Good, free resource, where you could look at, eg, addressing modes: [Bartlett](ftp://gnu.mirrors.pair.com/savannah/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, any computer program uses an one-dimensional array of bytes called memory. The `base address` and `offset` are numbers, which is used to map a data structure to memory. Let, for example, concider the following C structure:

```
struct My {
  struct My* next;
  int a,b;
} first;
```

This structure is placed somewhere in memory. The base address of `first` is the index of the first byte of the structure, and the offsets are the indexes of first bytes of structure fields relative to the structure beginning.
IE `first.a=256` translates to `mov [first+first_a], 256`.

A `pointer` in assembler is essentially the same as a pointer in C.